# In what way can you style a Session Flash message in PHP with CSS?

Tags: php, html, css

Within my PHP registration page I have the following code:

```
Session::flash('home', 'Registration Successful! You may now login!');
Redirect::to('index.php');
```

So once the user's details have been inserted into database it then redirects to index page and displays the success message.

Currently this message looks plain and boring. Is it possible to style the message with CSS and how do I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: `Session::flash('home', '<p style="font-size:77px; color:red;">Registration Successful! You may now login!</p>');`

Comment: Oh wow thanks, I didn't actually realize it was that simple. So if I wanted to I could put this in a Div and do some styling externally?

Comment: I think that in all regards @KristerAndersson commented with a very bad solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use anything that HTML and CSS and Javascript offers.

PHP does not offer a Session flash message, this is a feature of some framework code you use, so you probably should have a look at the manual about how to access that flash message again, how to wrap it into HTML (probably inside a template), and subsequently you are free to assign any needed CSS attributes, classes or ids you need to style it.